# Command line interface for Photos App in WIndows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, photos

Let's say I have a few images in a directory. When I double-click one of them it opens up in the photos app and I can view the other images using left/right arrow keys. However the behavior is different when the app is launched from command prompt.

I have not found a proper way of invoking the app from command prompt while supplying a filename. The best I found is `start ms-photos:` which launches the app but ignores any other arguments.

`start <file_name>` or simply `<file_name>` works and launches the app with the requested image, but now the app is unable to view the other images in the directory (left/right doesn't work; it acts as if only that image is present).

Is there any way to make sure the app is able to view all the images in the directory? (current directory while executing the command is already the directory containing the images)

Comment: Short answer: No. Universal apps do not support command line options.

Comment: For command line usages, old Windows Photo Viewer can be used.

Comment: Even the Com approach:  `Shell.ofolder.folderitem.InvokeVerb()` approach didn't produce the previous/next arrows that the identical clicks produce. :(

Comment: I know more than a year old, but I'm very interested in an answer to this question, such that we can open the Photos app such that left/right will let us switch through the image files in that folder.

Answer (score 2):

I found that this will open the default application.

```
start "" "Name of File.ext"
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. When I open a file with `start "" "Name of File.ext"`, left/right still does not work; as per the original question, it acts as if only a single image is present, and you cannot left/right to view other image files in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command which will open the default application.

```
start " " Name of File.extension
Example: start " " mypic.png
```

Comment: Why did you copy/paste previous answer?